# AWK command is not working as expected on AIX

Tags: csv, awk, aix

I have written below script to merge 2 files based on common column name , it ran as expected on linux machine but when I execute same one on AIX it is throwing error

Input Files:

```
[user@XXXXX ~]$ cat file1.csv

TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_01-02-21,PCT_FREE_02-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50,50
TESTDTAI,50,50
USERSPACE1,98,98
TEMP32K,0,0
TEMP4K,0,0
TESTDTAL,49,49
TESTDTAT4K,50,50
TESTDTAT32K,0,0
TESTCTLI,8,8
TESTCTLL,0,0
TESTCTLT4K,2,2
TESTCTLT32K,25,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0,0

[user@XXXXX ~]$ cat file2.csv
TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_03-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50
TESTDTAI,50
USERSPACE1,98
TEMP32K,0
TEMP4K,0
TESTDTAL,49
TESTDTAT4K,50
TESTDTAT32K,0
TESTCTLI,8
TESTCTLL,0
TESTCTLT4K,2
TESTCTLT32K,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0`
```

Command :

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=$s$(i)","}{print $s"," a[$1]}' \
     file2.csv \
     file1.csv > tablespace_growth_`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`.csv
```

output on Linux machine:

```
TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_01-02-21,PCT_FREE_02-02-21,PCT_FREE_03-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50,50,50
TESTDTAI,50,50,50
USERSPACE1,98,98,98
TEMP32K,0,0,0
TEMP4K,0,0,0
TESTDTAL,49,49,49
TESTDTAT4K,50,50,50
TESTDTAT32K,0,0,0
TESTCTLI,8,8,8
TESTCTLL,0,0,0
TESTCTLT4K,2,2,2
TESTCTLT32K,25,25,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94,94,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0,0,0
```

output on AIX :

```
awk: 0602-562 Field $() is not correct.
 The input line number is 1. The file is file1.csv.
 The source line number is 1.
```

Please help on this .

Comment: `{print $s"," a[$1]}` seems having issue. You use a dollar sign (`$`) to refer to a field in an awk program, followed by the number of the field you want. Thus, `$1` refers to the first field, `$2` to the second, and so on.

Comment: Instead of `$s` use `s` -- the different awk versions aren't entirely compatible when it comes to syntax errors: some variants are more tolerant than others.

Comment: On Linux you're probably running gawk so add the `--lint` flag (`awk --lint -F...`) and read the warnings it gives you, in particular: `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file1.csv FNR=16) warning: attempt to field reference from non-numeric value
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0,0,0`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{print $s"," a[$1]}` seems having issue. You use a dollar sign ($) to refer to a field in an awk program, followed by the number of the field you want. Thus, `$1` refers to the first field, `$2` to the second, and so on.

Its actually producing internally

```
{print $0 "," a[$1]}
```

Because your variable `s` is non numeric will evaluate to zero (`0`)

If you observe your code closely

> awk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1] = $2; next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=$s$(i)","}{print $s"," a[$1]}' 
> file2.csv 
> file1.csv > tablespace_growth_`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`.csv

**After the end of for loop (you're just overwriting same `s=$s$(i)","` in each iteration)**

```
Actual value of s=TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_01-02-21,PCT_FREE_02-02-21PCT_FREE_02-02-21,
```

Will evaluate to zero (`0`) hence prints current record followed by array value.

**To Demonstrate further:**

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8

$ awk '{ string_val="non-numeric"; printf("$(%d) => %s\n", string_val,$(string_val))}' testfile.txt
$(0) => 1 2
$(0) => 3 4
$(0) => 5 6
$(0) => 7 8

$ awk '{ string_val="2"; printf("$(%d) => %s\n", string_val,$(string_val))}' testfile.txt
$(2) => 2
$(2) => 4
$(2) => 6
$(2) => 8
```

**Below may help you:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}$1 in arr{print $0,arr[$1]}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

**OR even**

```
   awk 'BEGIN{
           FS=OFS=","
         }
         FNR==NR{
           arr[$1]=$2;
           next
         } 
         {
           printf("%s%s%s",$0,(($1 in arr)?OFS arr[$1]:""),RS)
         }' file2.csv file1.csv
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}$1 in arr{print $0,arr[$1]}' file2.csv file1.csv
TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_01-02-21,PCT_FREE_02-02-21,PCT_FREE_03-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50,50,50
TESTDTAI,50,50,50
USERSPACE1,98,98,98
TEMP32K,0,0,0
TEMP4K,0,0,0
TESTDTAL,49,49,49
TESTDTAT4K,50,50,50
TESTDTAT32K,0,0,0
TESTCTLI,8,8,8
TESTCTLL,0,0,0
TESTCTLT4K,2,2,2
TESTCTLT32K,25,25,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94,94,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0,0,0
```

**Input:**

```
$ cat file1.csv 
TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_01-02-21,PCT_FREE_02-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50,50
TESTDTAI,50,50
USERSPACE1,98,98
TEMP32K,0,0
TEMP4K,0,0
TESTDTAL,49,49
TESTDTAT4K,50,50
TESTDTAT32K,0,0
TESTCTLI,8,8
TESTCTLL,0,0
TESTCTLT4K,2,2
TESTCTLT32K,25,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0,0

$ cat file2.csv 
TABLESPACE_name,PCT_FREE_03-02-21
SYSCATSPACE,50
TESTDTAI,50
USERSPACE1,98
TEMP32K,0
TEMP4K,0
TESTDTAL,49
TESTDTAT4K,50
TESTDTAT32K,0
TESTCTLI,8
TESTCTLL,0
TESTCTLT4K,2
TESTCTLT32K,25
SYSTOOLSPACE,94
SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE,0
```